# style.css not being rendered in browser

Tags: theme-development, twitter-bootstrap

I created a new theme with underscores starter theme. I properly enqueued the style.css and boostrap.min.css, but my navigation menu is still not reflecting the styles from style.css. It is showing a list-style type of bullet and the wrong font, font-size and color. The bootstrap css properties are being reflected.

Checked it in firebug and got 200 OK, so I do not believe it is cached.

Firebug also shows that style.css is being loaded.

Can post my code if needed. Thanks.

Comment: If you are referring to default style.css in theme root folder, then there is no need to enqueue it. Only enqueue the bootstrap css and you are good to go

Comment: Show us the code by which you've enqueued the stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out twice, the stylesheet of Underscores boilerplate is pretty empty as you can see in [the github repo](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/style.css). That's the point of Underscores, you must create your own CSS styles, including menus.

Can you paste the enqueueing snippet, the relative URL and the content of that style.css file that you mentioned above?